# QR Code Scanning inside a limit area

Tags: android

I'm new to android. I'm using Google vision-api dependency for Qr-code scanning by following the link below :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INVNULTm56o .

But it scanning the whole screen. If i want to read Qr-code from a limit area or a Boundary without minimize the screen is it possible? Let me Know Thank you.

I design this boundary in my app and i want read Qr Code from only from boundary:-

[image]

Comment: Use this library:
 https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4516

Comment: Could you use any library for Qr Code scanner ? @Ashraf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Zxing Library for **QR-code Scanne**r as well **Barcode Scanner**.

If you want to customize your Layout:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49105489/8448886

You can also handle `onCreate()` ,`onResume()` , `onPause()` with this Library.

[image]

**build.gradle(Module:app) file**

```
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
```

Java code **ScanActivity**  :

```
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
    setContentView(mScannerView);                // Set the scanner view as the content view
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
    mScannerView.startCamera();          // Start camera on resume
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    // Do something with the result here
    Log.v("tag", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
    Log.v("tag", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)



    // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
    //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
}
```

You will get Scanner Result on :

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    // Do something with the result here
     Log.v("tag", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
     Log.v("tag", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)



    // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
    //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
```